# Project management and bug tracking software

Tags: project-management, startup, bug-tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Project Management tool for bugs and projects together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366301/project-management-tool-for-bugs-and-projects-together)

I've been looking for a service that offers bug tracking + project management and maybe a place where we can write ideas ( like an idea repository ).

We're a small start-up consisting of only 2 people ( developers ). We're looking for a free service, doesn't matter if it's hosted online or if we have to host it on our servers.

By the way, I've really looked a lot and I just couldn't find the perfect solution for us, so any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find something that really fits our needs. Do you know of any solution that consists of a place where we can save our ideas like an Idea repo? Also we need something that's free.

Answer (score 2):

For such a small group you can get the atlassian software for something like 10$ I think. With Jira (Issue tracking) and Confluence (wiki) you would have a solid base to grow from.

Comment: Although this is a good idea, it must be said that Atlassian's products have a learning curve and they aren't that straight forward - especially if you don't have a highly structured development process.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub](https://github.com/features/projects) is a good alternative to check. Does everything you asked for. There is a free option for open source projects, and you can pay for private repositories as well.

Comment: We're looking for a free service but we're not doing open source projects at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an idea repo, why not use an online note-taking site/program? [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) is great for this as it also syncs with other computers, web, phones, etc. It arranges/categorizes them neatly, lets you take pictures.

For a quick and simple project management tool, I use [Wedoist](https://wedoist.com/). It's really easy to set up; suitable for very small teams. You can use a tag/folder for bugs, and prioritize it if you wish. Almost no learning curve.